# What are these characters from this chopsticks packaging?

Tags: classical-chinese, character-identification, calligraphy

What are the characters shown in the following chopsticks packaging?

I've no idea what the first character is and the Chinese speakers at the restaurant at which I was given this package couldn't identify it either.

The second character appears to be 箸, a classical and dialectical word for chopsticks. However, that leaves me curious as to why there's a dot at the right-hand side of the 者 component.

[image: Chopsticks Packaging]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

御 royal; imperial

箸 chopsticks

The dot at the right-hand side of the 者 component is due to [different typefaces](http://www.zdic.net/z/20/zy/7BB8.htm).

[image]

Comment: 御箸 is the Japanese word *ohashi*, where 御 (o-) is an honorific prefix.